# SwingWorker updating multiple combos, lists, tables by using one map

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, swingworker

Following a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028016/swingworker-updating-multiple-comboboxes-in-multilpe-panels) question, which was solved, I can fill multiple comboboxes with a `SwingWorker` using one `HashMap`. Now I want to fill/update multiple comboboxes AND lists AND tables that are contained in different panels of a gui app, by using one map (if possible). In the javadocs I saw that both `DefaultListModel` and `DefaultComboBoxModel` extend `AbstractListModel`, so I changed the Map from

```
Map<String, DefaultComboBoxModel>
```

to

```
Map<String, AbstractListModel>
```

which is then passed to the `SwingWorker`. The following code works and it can fill many combos and lists by using this one map.

SSCCE:

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    private final Map<String, AbstractListModel> map = new HashMap<String, AbstractListModel>();

    private TestPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
        JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();
        JList list1 = new JList(new DefaultListModel());
        JList list2 = new JList(new DefaultListModel());
        add(combo1);
        add(combo2);
        add(new JLabel("LIST 1:"));
        add(list1);
        add(new JLabel("LIST 2:"));
        add(list2);
        map.put("ComboBox1", (DefaultComboBoxModel)combo1.getModel());
        map.put("ComboBox2", (DefaultComboBoxModel)combo2.getModel());
        map.put("List1", (DefaultListModel)list1.getModel());
        map.put("List2", (DefaultListModel)list2.getModel());
        new MyWorker(map).run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPanel());
                frame.setSize(200, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Object[]> {
        private final int COMBO_BOX_MODEL = 1;
        private final int LIST_MODEL = 2;
        private final Map<String, AbstractListModel> map;

        public MyWorker(Map<String, AbstractListModel> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // just a random way to fill the combos and the lists
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                Object[] cell = new Object[3];
                if (i>=0 && i<=4) {
                    cell[0] = "ComboBox1";
                    cell[1] = COMBO_BOX_MODEL;
                } else if (i>=5 && i<=9) {
                    cell[0] = "ComboBox2";
                    cell[1] = COMBO_BOX_MODEL;
                } else if (i>=10 && i<=14) {
                    cell[0] = "List1";
                    cell[1] = LIST_MODEL;
                } else if (i>=15 && i<=20) {
                    cell[0] = "List2";
                    cell[1] = LIST_MODEL;
                }
                cell[2] = "value " + i;
                publish(cell);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
            for (Object[] chunk : chunks) {
                if (chunk[1] == Integer.valueOf(COMBO_BOX_MODEL)) {
                    DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)map.get(chunk[0]);
                    model.addElement(chunk[2]);
                }
                else if (chunk[1] == Integer.valueOf(LIST_MODEL)) {
                    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)map.get(chunk[0]);
                    model.addElement(chunk[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Question 1: While the above code works, I don't like how it looks (in particular the checking in the `process()` method). Is there any better and/or more clever way to do the whole thing?

Question 2: Is there any way to make the `SwingWorker` to update tables too along with the combos and the lists, by using one map? I couldn't find a way since `DefaultTableModel` extends `AbstractTableModel` which is different from `AbstractListModel` that is used by the map.

I hope I was clear, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your data source no doubt has a different type system than Java; the code to match those types to Java types won't be any prettier, but at least you've got it encapsulated. An `enum` may help.
2. Yes, you can extend `AbstractTableModel` and implement the other interfaces by delegating to a default implementation. There's an outline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572903/230513). You'll have to decide if such a bottleneck makes sense in your application.

   ```
   public class SharedModel extends AbstractTableModel
       implements ComboBoxModel, ListModel
   ```

Addendum: The alternative is to write three models (`MyTableModel`, `MyListModel`, `MyComboBoxModel`) that each reference a common data model.

> *Do you mean a common interface that is implemented by three models?*

Yes, an interface that is implemented by a class, say `ApplicationDataModel`, that reads the database into an internal format. Client models can then ask the `ApplicationDataModel` for the data each needs to fulfill its own interface contract.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted. SharedModel cannot be cast to DefaultComboBoxModel or DefaultListModel since it extends AbstractTableModel. So the checking must be moved into SharedModel where I should add methods with two versions (like addElement) depending on the type of component (combo or list). Or at least this is how I understand it. Am I correct? If yes then you're right about the bottleneck. SharedModel can get complex trying to decide which version to use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Do you mean to make a common interface that is implemented by three models?

Comment: got it, that's better I think

Comment: I went ahead an promoted a summary of the comments to the answer.